# HTTP Authentication equivalent for cURL username:password

Tags: http, curl, get, postman

Is there a way to convert the following curl into an normal http request?

`curl --user <username>:<password> https://{username}.fred.sensetecnic.com/api/{custom_endpoint_name}`

Into something like this (using Postman for the http requests)

```
GET https://{username}.fred.sensetecnic.com/api/{custom_endpoint_name}

Headers: Username: username, Password: password
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'normal http request'? That second snippet doesn't really look like any http request I've seen. have you read: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7617

Comment: Sorry if the code bracket made it confusing. It's not command line code. I meant is there a way to use Headers instead of the <username>:<passowrd> that curl provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Basic Auth` provided in postman.

1. Goto `Authorization` tab.
2. Select `Basic Auth` from Type dropdown list.
3. Add username and password.
4. Click Update request(if applicable).

[image]

---

Note: For this to work, server must accept json encoded credentials.

1. Click on `Headers`.
2. Select `Content type`
3. Add `key-value` pairs, Username and Password

   [image]

Comment: Whats the response

Comment: Unauthorized: Access denied

Comment: Try basic auth in Authorization tab